# How to install light-weight vim and to be able to efficiently load files into one instance vim?

Tags: command-line, vim, editors, console, efficiency

On my laptop with Ubuntu I'm able to have just one instance of vim, launched with

```
vim --servername VIM
```

After this I'm able to open files from console with

```
vim --remote-silent filename
```

I use short aliases for both of them.

Also I do some computation on another computer (I'll call it workhorse). It has Debian x64 (without gui) installed. I usually access it using multiple instances of Putty from a Windows PC. Actually workhorse is a virtual machine and I pay for resource usage, so I don't want to overload it too much. However after usual installation of vim (`apt-get install vim`) I'm unable to run vim with --servername option. It says

```
Unknown option argument: "--servername"
More info with: vim -h
```

Indeed, [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html) says that vim should be compiled with [+client-server](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#+clientserver) option to run it as "a command server". I know two other options: `apt-get install vim-gtk` and `apt-get install vim-gnome`, but they ask for huge installation (136Mb and 245Mb respectively). As far as I understand this is somehow related with installation of graphical interface.

I don't have any preferences for any particular workaround. Probably, I will be happy with any workable solution. But I do want to load files to vim from console, like I'm doing it from Ubuntu, or otherwise I do want to know any other way to effectively use vim for editing multiple files. So the question remains

How to install light-weight vim and to be able to efficiently load files into one instance vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The client-server capabilities of `vim` depend on X11, citing from [its help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html#x11-clientserver):

> **The communication between client and server goes through the X server.**  The
>   display of the Vim server must be specified.  The usual protection of the X
>   server is used, you must be able to open a window on the X server for the
>   communication to work.
>
> [...]
>
> **A non GUI Vim with access to the X11 display (`xterm-clipboard` enabled), can
>   also act as a command server if a server name is explicitly given with the
>   `--servername` argument.**

[This mailing list post](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use/msg/8a4253d1ba925bf4) is clearer on what is needed:

> Except on Windows, communication between server and client goes
>   through X11, so in that case you need both the `--with-x` configuration
>   option (or default) at compile-time (which, in turn, requires one or
>   more X11 "development" packages to be installed) and **an available X
>   server at run-time.**

**Thus**, if you're concerned with resources on your "workhorse", it might be better to just fire up `vim` instances when needed.

**Edit:** You could get away with "less than `gvim`" by building `vim` yourself (e.g. by rebuilding the Debian package ([packaging tutorial PDF](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/packaging-tutorial/packaging-tutorial.pdf))) such that while still needing X11, you could do without GTK etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question. It clarified things I was trying to read from help a lot. Mostly I'm concerned with RAM usage. So I don't actually worry about HDD usage, so even 400Mb installation would be probably ok, if it doesn't use RAM every day. So X server as far as I understand, requires about 30Mb of RAM, so it's not very "cheap".

Comment: Although it's not an answer to your question, you might be interested in [this approach](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/bcvi/): utilizing a SSH session's "back-channel" to use a feature-full *local* `gvim` for editing *remote* files. (I guess it also works with a local `vim`; also I don't know anything about this approaches memory usage, I merely suspect it could be rather low.)

Comment: I am accessing "workhorse" from Windows, using putty. Do you think this approach is possible with putty?

Comment: Oh, I forgot that.  Hm, ` bcvi` is written in Perl, but it needs some listener script running locally (i.e., on the windows machine); it could be possible but, I'm sorry, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, this is the first time I've heard about the client-server mode of vim. And to me, it does not look useful in your scenario, since you can edit as many files as you want in one vim instance using **tabs**. When in `vim`, just enter `:tabedit somefile` and a new tab will open with the selected file. Simple tab switching is done using `gt` command.

For more on tabs, see `help tabs` (from within vim). Also have a look at `help split` if you'd like to see more than one file at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can open multiple files in vim. I just wanted to be able to open them without typing full path in vim.

Comment: You can make it easier using copy-paste (`realpath` might come in handy to display full path to a file). And the vim command line has also Tab-completion functionality similar to your shell.